# Windows 7 in Compatibility Mode options on Windows 7 Enterprise

Tags: windows-7

Does anyone have any ideas as to why Windows 7 is listed in compatibility mode options, for any executable I go into this tab of the Properties dialog for, on my Windows 7 Enterprise install?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7 (RTM) = Build 7600 and if you use the Windows 7 Sp1 which is Build 7601. Maybe this helps to run software which checks for Build 7600 only.

Comment: Hi, any idea why [Win8's compatibility mode list](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lZubV.png) doesn't include Win7 SP1?

Comment: @Karan I have no idea. Ask this Microsoft.

Comment: I had wondered this, but I noticed that the option to pick Service Packs of you running version of Windows doesn't exist in Windows XP patched to SP3, nor Vista patched to SP2 (Being the two versions of Windows readily available to me. Would be great if this line mentioned "(No SP)", or similar, to make this more clear (Does anyone know if this is a registry setting / easy hack?). Curious also that there would be programs designed only for Build 7600. Marking as answer until such time (if ever) someone else has another theory that pans out.